# How to find values in certain row numbers, 100th, 200th ... 1500th etc

Tags: date, google-sheets, filter, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I have dates in column A; I have an API that writes into my google sheet.
I have 1500 such rows with various dates. I want to know the dates in the 100th, 200th,.. rows, so that I can subtract those dates and find how long it took for first 100 rows to get added, then how long it took for second 100 rows to get added.. similarly how long it took for 1400th to 1500th row to get added. Something like this...

```
A(1,1) =  02/01/2018
...
A(100,1) = 03/15/2018
....
A(200,1) = 04/10/2018
....
```

I want to find when the 100th entry was added; so I could do simple = A200-A100; etc.

Comment: share a copy of your sheet with example of desired output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(DAYS(
      FILTER(A:A, MOD(ROW(A:A), 100)=0), 
 {A1; FILTER(A:A, MOD(ROW(A:A), 100)=0)})))
```

example of 10-row range:

[image: 0]

Comment: Thanks! it worked great, except the last one, which had 1575 (just as example) rows, we get error. So worked for range between row 1 to 1500; I will need to wait till 1600th row gets added.

Comment: you can track down the last value like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/oqNOc.png